# The Relationship between Coordinates and SpaceTime

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, covariance

I was reading a paper describing the contributions integral mathematicians and physicists have made in the advancement of physics by Michael Atiyah (https://www.jstor.org/stable/24111066), but have come across a potential contradiction in the author’s words. I wanted to understand this point fully, as I am wary I may just be misunderstanding his language.

In the body of the section, Atiyah notes:

“The connection between physics and geometry starts at the conceptual stage in a fully 3-dimensional picture of the world, **and has nothing to do with any reference frame which one may choose to take measurements.**

Descartes’ introduction of coordinates may have been an essential step in the formalization of mathematical physics but it was also an abdication-it gave up on trying to understand physics geometrically.

In the conclusion of that section, he then goes on to say

“
Standard textbooks make great play with the technical details, including coordinates, writing equations and then showing that the resulting physics is **independent of the choice of coordinates**. To a geometer, this is perverse.
“

I originally thought this meant that since geometry and physics are interconnected, it is perverse to say coordinates and geometry are independent. However, in the body,it says the connection *has nothing to do with the “reference frame”*, which I’m interpreting as the coordinates.

What does Atiyah mean by saying coordinate choice’s independence is perverse? Was I interpreting it right in my original notion or is it something different altogether?

Comment: I think Atiyah means that the "roundabout" approach of first introducing coordinates, writing equations, and then showing the resulting physics is coordinate-independent is the perverse part. He (being a mathematician) would much rather have everything written down coordinate-free from the beginning. He is not saying that coordinate-independence is perverse; that would indeed be absurd, because coordinate-independence is what we expect and what we want and what we love.

Comment: What the author is calling perverse is the method of, by manipulation of equalities between coordinates, proving the invariance of physics. He means that, to a geometer, it doesn't make sense to use coordinates to prove a geometrical result, because the only objects that they would ever need are geometric ones